# Substitute numpy array elements using dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have this numpy array

```
message = [ 97 98 114 97]
```

and this dictionary

```
codes = {97: '1', 98: '01', 114: '000'}
```

and I am now iterating through the numpy array and converting those numbers to the ones corresponding in the dictionary like this:

```
[codes[i] for i in message]
```

But this is really slow and takes a lot of memory, since I am creating a new list. Is there better approach? Maybe one in which I will have still the same numpy array, but with the new numbers like this?

```
message = [1 01 000 1]
```

Comment: What `dtype` do you want in the result?  Int, strings, ?

Comment: I want them to be strings

Comment: Strings like this, especially if they can vary in length, can't be put 'back' into an integer array.  You must produce a new list, or string type array based  on such a list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *NumPythonic* solution using [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
np.asarray(codes.values())[np.searchsorted(codes.keys(),message)]
```

Please note that the output would be a NumPy array as well. If you would like to have a list output, wrap it with `.tolist()` -

```
np.asarray(codes.values())[np.searchsorted(codes.keys(),message)].tolist()
```

I would think the only bottleneck to this approach would be conversion to NumPy array with `np.asarray()`, as usually `np.searchsorted` is pretty efficient.

Sample run -

```
In [36]: message = [ 97, 98, 114, 97]

In [37]: codes = {97: '1', 98: '01', 114: '000'}

In [38]: [codes[i] for i in message]
Out[38]: ['1', '01', '000', '1']

In [39]: np.asarray(codes.values())[np.searchsorted(codes.keys(),message)]
Out[39]: 
array(['1', '01', '000', '1'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Comment: This approach turns the original problem on its head.  Instead of replacing values in `message` with corresponding values from the dictionary, it selects values from the dictionary that match `message`.  Often the best `numpy` solutions involve this sort of inversion.

Comment: For `message=np.random.randint(0,100,200)` your approach takes about the same time as the list comprehension - give or take a bit depending on whether the list is turned back into an array.

Comment: can you explain what searchsorted is doing here?

Comment: @riotburn Well in this case, `searchsorted` is basically looking for places or indices where elements from `message` exists in the keys of `codes` . Those indices are then used to index into the values of codes to give us the string NumPy array output.

Answer (score 0):

you can very simply update in place:

```
for i in np.arange(len(message)):
   message[i] = codes.get(message[i], message[i])
```

I'm sure there's a numpy specific syntax to iterate.  But note, you don't preserve the byte string since `messages` is of int type and your dict values appear to be byte arrays.  So you would need to copy to a new array to preserve type.

Comment: I considered the same thing, but I would be curious to know if this is actually any faster.  I just did a little testing and couldn't see any real difference in this application between a list comprehension, a generator, and updating in place.  Granted, my test case may have been too simple, but I'd like to hear from the OP if this speeds things up for them.

Comment: I tried it on a large file which I am working with and it made it a lot slower. My original approac took 5s, this one takes 14s. It does use less ram though. I have found out another approach:
newArray = copy(message); for k, v in codes.iteritems(): newArray[message==k] = v;
it does the exact same thing as yours, but uses significantly less ram and is almost the same speed wise. But ut returns me array of ints, so in my case [1 1 0 1] like you said. How could I make the array show those bits or strings like in my question?

Comment: Building the new array isn't the time consumer.  It's the repeated dictionary access.

Comment: sorry, I only read the big memory issue. Didn't attempt a solution for speed.  Why would repeated dictionary access be slow?  Isn't that O(1)?

Comment: How does your version compare in speed?  `for i,v in enumerate(message)` will speed up your version.